# ruby gem - rally_api dependency

Tags: rally

If I use gem 'rally_api' it will use version 0.9.8, which will failed to login rally with api_key
If I use gem 'rally_api', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.1' to install latest version 1.2.1(I mannully install in my local machine), the rake task can work, but I'll get compatible version error:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "httpclient":
  In Gemfile:
    berkshelf (~> 4.3.5) was resolved to 4.3.5, which depends on
      httpclient (~> 2.7)

```
rally_api (>= 1.2.1, ~> 1.2) was resolved to 1.2.1, which depends on
  httpclient (= 2.6.0.1)
```

Comment: did you try to do gem update for all gems? and see that may fixes it.

Comment: Yes, sure, but this still exist, it can't fix this one